# Download and extract archive using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wget, tar, 7-zip, curl

Using PowerShell 5.1, how can I download a `tar.xz` archive and extract it without writing it to disk first?

All these attempts:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://www.examle.com/archive.tar.xz -UseBasicParsing | 7z x -si
(Invoke-WebRequest https://www.examle.com/archive.tar.xz -UseBasicParsing).ToString() | 7z x -si
(Invoke-WebRequest https://www.examle.com/archive.tar.xz -UseBasicParsing).Content | 7z x -si
(Invoke-WebRequest https://www.examle.com/archive.tar.xz -UseBasicParsing).RawContent | 7z x -si
```

Gives this error:

```
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Extracting archive:
ERROR:
Can not open encrypted archive. Wrong password?

Not implemented

Can't open as archive: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0
```

This works:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://www.examle.com/archive.tar.xz -UseBasicParsing -OutFile temp.tar.xz
7z x temp.tar.xz
```

Comment: If you have a working command, what exactly, is your question?  You understand either method would end up writing a temporary cache to the disk

Comment: It works, but I would like to not explicitly create the temporary file and have to explicitly delete it again afterwards.

Comment: You cant do that.  7zip isnt designed to take piped data.

Comment: I think it is: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/stdin.htm

Comment: Isn't that showing a `7z` command being piped to another `7z` command? Does `7z` support piping raw output and/or string values to a `7z` command though? Do you have any post URLs where that may be indicated? Why is there such concern with writing it to disk in your case anyway? Help paint me a picture and I may teach you how to fish!!

Comment: I don't actually have a concern with writing to disk first, but I don't understand why I can't get the piped solution to work. `7z` can write to stdout, yes: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/stdout.htm

Comment: @MagnarMyrtveit powershell doesn't support raw byte stream (yet), so you can't pipe a binary stream to a 7z instance. All inputs and outputs will go through text encoding and decoding because the console to powershell is just a text device

Answer (score 3):

## Challenge: Download, extract xz archive in PowerShell

I describe two approaches to achieve the objective.

### Without writing anything to disk

By example, suppose we want to download/extract files from the `mingw32-dev.tar.xz` XZ archive available at [MinGW - Minimalist GNU for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/mingwrt/mingwrt-5.0.2/).

We can download without writing to disk as follows:

```powershell
$r=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://mirrors.gigenet.com/OSDN//mingw/70554/mingwrt-5.2.1-mingw32-dev.tar.xz'
```

Our target archive is available to shell as a byte array in `$r.Content`. How to extract?

Using [`SevenZipExtractor`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipExtractor/1.0.7) C# wrapper for 7Zip, we extract as follows:

```powershell
#Download and install from nuget.org
Install-Package SevenZipExtractor -Scope CurrentUser

#Add the SevenZip assembly to our current PowerShell session
(Get-Item (Join-Path (Split-Path (Get-Package SevenZipExtractor).Source) lib/netstandard*) |
  Sort-Object { [version] ($_.Name -replace '^netstandard') })[-1] |
    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse |
      ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Adding ``$($_.Name)``"; Add-Type -LiteralPath $_.FullName }
```

The `SevenZipExtractor` class includes, inter alia, the following overloaded constructor signatures:

```csharp
public SevenZipExtractor(Stream archiveStream);
public SevenZipExtractor(Stream archiveStream, string password);
public SevenZipExtractor(Stream archiveStream, SevenZipFormat format);
public SevenZipExtractor(Stream archiveStream, string password, InArchiveFormat format);
```

Here `Stream` means data-type `System.IO.Stream` and `SevenZipFormat` means type `SevenZipExtractor.SevenZipFormat`.

So we can use the SevenZipExtractor class by

```powershell
$sevenZipStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new(($r.Content))
$szExtractor = New-Object -TypeName SevenZipExtractor.ArchiveFile -ArgumentList @($sevenZipStream)
$szExtractor.Extract("$env:TEMP",$False) # Instead of $env:TEMP, wherever you want the files to go
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/mavaddat/1e75ab2df980aceac75d7d065f3210a1) is a working example I wrote that implements the above approach to download and install `ffmpeg`.

### Writing to temp file to disk

If we were writing the file to disk, the objective is more simple to achieve using the [`7Zip4Powershell` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/7Zip4PowerShell/1.10.0.0).

```powershell
Install-Module -Name 7Zip4Powershell
Import-Module -Name 7Zip4Powershell -Global
```

However, `7Zip4PowerShell` does not implement all the overloaded method signatures of `SevenZipExtractor`

[Since the Windows 10 Preview Build 17063](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/), bsdtar is included with PowerShell. To extract a tar.xz file, invoke the `tar` command with the `--extract` (`-x`) option and specify the archive file name after the `-f` option:

```powershell
tar -xf .\whatever.xz
```

`tar` auto-detects the compression type and extracts the archive. For more verbose output, use the `-v` option. This option tells `tar` to display the names of the files being extracted on the terminal.

### Ordinary zip file in memory

As a bonus, let's see how it works with ZIP. Here is an example in which I find `aes.h` inside the [ffmpeg source code](https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git) zip archive:

```powershell
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression')
    $IWRresult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/dev/ffmpeg-latest-win64-dev.zip"  -SslProtocol Tls12 -Method Get
    $zipStream = New-Object System.IO.Memorystream
    $zipStream.Write($IWRresult.Content,0,$IWRresult.Content.Length)
    $zipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]::new($zipStream)
    #OK, what's in the archive I just downloaded?
    #Write the archive contents to the shell output
    $zipFile.Entries | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty @('Archive','ExternalAttributes') | Format-Table #I don't care about 'Archive' or 'ExternalAttributes', so I instruct suppress those
    #oh, there's my `aes.h` inside `ffmpeg-latest-win64-dev/include/libavutil/`
    $entry =  $zipFile.GetEntry('ffmpeg-latest-win64-dev/include/libavutil/aes.h')
    #now we have a streamreader, we can do all the things
    #for example, let's output the content to the screen
    $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($entry.Open())
    Write-Host $reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Another example that aims to download archive, run EXE from that archive all in memory:

```powershell
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression')
    $IWRresult=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-20200424-a501947-win64-static.zip' -Method Get -SslProtocol Tls12
    $zipStream = New-Object System.IO.Memorystream
    $zipStream.Write($IWRresult.Content,0,$IWRresult.Content.Length)
    $zipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]::new($zipStream)
    #OK, what did I just download?
    #Write the contents to the shell output
    $zipFile.Entries | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty @('Archive','ExternalAttributes') | Format-Table #I don't care about 'Archive' or 'ExternalAttributes', so I instruct suppress those
    #I see there is 'ffmpeg-20200424-a501947-win64-static/bin/ffmpeg.exe' entry
    $zipEntry = $zipFile.GetEntry('ffmpeg-20200424-a501947-win64-static/bin/ffmpeg.exe')
    $binReader = [System.IO.BinaryReader]::new($zipEntry.Open())
    #need external modules `PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit` to be able to run exe from memory (without writing to disk); see comments below this code block
    Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection -PEBytes $binReader.ReadBytes() -ExeArgs "Arg1 Arg2 Arg3 Arg4"
```

Please see [PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit) for more information about how to run an EXE from the memory. Find examples here: [GitHub Examples](https://github.com/search?l=PowerShell&q=Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection&type=Code)